# Encryption output for CryptoJS and CryptoSwift for AES CBC are coming different

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, encryption, aes

Below is **Java Script** Code

```
var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var iterations = 1000;

var message = "Hello World";
var password = "secret";
var ivSfmc = "4963b7334a46352623252955df21d7f3";
var saltSFmc = "e0cf1267f564b362";
var encryptedString = "";

function encrypt(msg, pass) {

    salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(saltSFmc);
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivSfmc);

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
    keySize: keySize / 32,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    iterations: iterations
  });

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });

  encryptedString = encrypted.toString();
  return encryptedString;
}


function decrypt(transitmessage, pass) {
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivSfmc);
  salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(saltSFmc);


  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
    keySize: keySize / 32,
    iterations: iterations
  });

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  })
  return decrypted;
}

var encrypted = encrypt(message, password);
var decrypted = decrypt(encryptedString, password);
```

**Output**

Encrypted: ndLxNDM5BwSeqNfXAQ5P3g==
Decrypted: Hello World

Below is **Swift** code cross-verified many times for equivalence but still result are different

```
import UIKit
import CryptoSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        do {
            let password: [UInt8] = Array("secret".utf8)
            let salt = Array(hex: "e0cf1267f564b362")

            /* Generate a key from a `password`. Optional if you already have a key */
            let key = try PKCS5.PBKDF2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                iterations: 1000,
                keyLength: 32, /* AES-256 */
                variant: .sha256
            ).calculate()

            /* Generate random IV value. IV is public value. Either need to generate, or get it from elsewhere */
            let iv = Array(hex: "4963b7334a46352623252955df21d7f3")

            /* AES cryptor instance */
            let aes = try AES(key: key, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv), padding: .pkcs7)

            /* Encrypt Data */
            let inputData = Array("Hello World".utf8)
            let encryptedBytes = try aes.encrypt(inputData)
            let encryptedData = Data(encryptedBytes)
            print(encryptedData.base64EncodedString())

            /* Decrypt Data */
            let decryptedBytes = try aes.decrypt(encryptedData.bytes)
            let decryptedData = Data(decryptedBytes)
            print(String(bytes: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8)!)

        } catch ( let error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

Encrypted: n05I/Ub/GC/mzQRmlNTl7w==
Decrypted: Hello World

Since Encrypted values at both levels are different, I am not able to decrypt the string received from CryptoJS encryption, after lots of trials I am still stuck and not able to understand why there is a difference even though exact values are used at both ends, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine - A tag does not have to be considered here, since CBC is not authenticated encryption and therefore does not use a tag. Also, no concatenation of the IV/nonce and ciphertext is necessary for successful decryption or compatibility of the codes. However, for security reasons, salt and IV should be randomly generated (so then concatenation of salt, IV and ciphertext is a possible option to transfer salt and IV along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both codes different digests are applied, which is why the ciphertexts are different (for the same input data: salt, IV, message, and password):

- In the CryptoJS code, the digest for PBKDF2 is not explicitly specified so the CryptoJS default SHA-1 is used.
- In the Swift code, the digest for PBKDF2 is explicitly specified as SHA-256 (which is also the CryptoSwift default).

For the ciphertexts to be identical, the same digests must be used.

---

So in the CryptoJS code, apply either SHA-256:

```js
...
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
    keySize: keySize / 32,
    iterations: iterations,
    hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256    // Fix, default: SHA1
});
...
```

```js
var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var iterations = 1000;

var message = "Hello World";
var password = "secret";
var ivSfmc = "4963b7334a46352623252955df21d7f3";
var saltSFmc = "e0cf1267f564b362";
var encryptedString = "";

function encrypt(msg, pass) {

    var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(saltSFmc);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivSfmc);

    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterations,
        hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256    // Fix, default: SHA1
    });

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,    // default
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC             // default
    });

    encryptedString = encrypted.toString();
    return encryptedString;
}


function decrypt(encrypted, pass) {
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivSfmc);
    var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(saltSFmc);


    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterations,
        hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256    // Fix, default: SHA1
    });

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,    // default
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC             // default
    });
    
    return decrypted;
}

var message = "Hello World"
var password = "secret";
var encrypted = encrypt(message, password);
var decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password);

console.log(encryptedString.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));  // for SHA256:        n05I/Ub/GC/mzQRmlNTl7w==
                                                                                                                         // for SHA1, default: ndLxNDM5BwSeqNfXAQ5P3g==
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

or alternatively in the Swift code SHA-1:

```swift
...
let key = try PKCS5.PBKDF2(
    password: password,
    salt: salt,
    iterations: 1000,
    keyLength: 32, /* AES-256 */
    variant: .sha1                  // Fix, default: SHA256
).calculate()
...
```

---

*Security:*

The use of a static salt and IV are vulnerabilities. Usually salt and IV are randomly generated for each encryption, concatenated with the ciphertext (e.g. salt|iv|ciphertext) and sent to the decrypting side. There they are separated based on the agreed/known lengths for salt and IV (keep in mind that salt and IV are not a secret).
Although SHA-1 is broken, it is not considered insecure in the context of PBKDF2 (nevertheless, it makes sense to stop using this digest so that it disappears from the ecosystem).
An iterations count of 1000 is generally too low for PBKDF2. The value should be set as high as possible while maintaining acceptable performance.
Instead of CBC, authenticated encryption such as GCM should be used if possible (unfortunately this is not supported by CryptoJS).

Comment: Thank you for solving the issue, and sure will take forward your suggestions during implementation.